# Is returning null bad design?

Tags: oop, null, return-value

I've heard some voices saying that checking for a returned null value from methods is bad design. I would like to hear some reasons for this.

pseudocode:

```
variable x = object.method()
if (x is null) do something
```

Comment: Elaborate: where are these people who say it's bad? Links?

Comment: If the method is something you have control over, you can have unit tests to make sure it never returns null, otherwise, I don't see why it would be a bad practice to check if it's null, after that call; it maybe a bad practice on that method to return null, but you have to protect your code

Comment: I expect the people who say it’s bad, prefer to use exceptions.

Comment: Raising exceptions just because there is no data to be returned is incredibly annoying. Normal program flow should not throw exceptions.

Comment: That's right. If you write the method and you know it can't return null, you don't need the performance hit/extra messy code of the check. But of course if you think checking for nulls is slowing down your code then you have bigger problems: have you done actual profiling to avoid premature optimization? Are you using value types/pointers/C to get actual performance gains?

Comment: @Thorarin:  There are methods that should return data.  Throwing an exception because they can't return data is fine.  If the method maybe should return data, then it's better off returning a null or something like that.

Comment: @David: That's what I said really. If a method should return data, but there is none, that means something also went wrong. That's not normal program flow :)

Comment: @Thorarin: "normal" program flow is quite a stretchable concept: not really a solid basis for an argument.

Comment: [Why NULL is Bad?](http://www.yegor256.com/2014/05/13/why-null-is-bad.html)

Comment: @jcollum One example is [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/565237) by Tom Hawtin, whose profile says he is a Java engineer at Oracle.

Comment: Another approach is to use the 'Optional' pattern to wrap the returned value with an object that upon success contains the returned value, and an empty object upon failure. Some languages (Java, Scala and more) have implementations of this pattern You can read more about it here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Option_type

Answer (score 224, accepted):

The rationale behind not returning null is that you do not have to check for it and hence your code does not need to **follow a different path** based on the return value.  You might want to check out the [Null Object Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) which provides more information on this.

For example, if I were to define a method in Java that returned a Collection I would typically prefer to return an empty collection (i.e. `Collections.emptyList()`) rather than null as it means my client code is cleaner; e.g.

```
Collection<? extends Item> c = getItems(); // Will never return null.

for (Item item : c) { // Will not enter the loop if c is empty.
  // Process item.
}
```

... which is cleaner than:

```
Collection<? extends Item> c = getItems(); // Could potentially return null.

// Two possible code paths now so harder to test.
if (c != null) {
  for (Item item : c) {
    // Process item.
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, way better than returning null and hoping the client remembers to deal with the case.

Comment: I'll happily agree that returning null is insane when it's used as a substitute for empty containers (or strings). That's not the common case though.

Comment: +1 for the Null Object Pattern for me too. Also when I actually want to return null, I have been naming the method like getCustomerOrNull() to make it explicit.  I think a method is named well when the reader doesn't want to look at the implementation.

Comment: The comment '// Two possible code paths now' is not correct; you have two code paths in either way. However, with the null Collection object in your first example, the 'null' code path is shorter. You still have two paths though, and you still need to test two paths.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe: Technically the first code example would compile down to having a single branch instruction (i.e. 2 code paths), whereas the second would have two branch instructions: one for the null check and one to check when c is empty (hence 4 possible paths).

Comment: @MSalters - arguably **every** variable in OO languages with `null` is a "container", which contains zero or one pointers to objects.  (That's certainly how it's explicitly modelled by Haskell's `Maybe` in those cases, and is all the better for doing so.)

Comment: @AndrzejDoyle: We were discussing hypotheticals here, not actual implementations. E.g. C++ has `boost::optional<T>` which also is a "container of at most one T". My earlier comment boils down to the redundancy of `optional<container<T>>`, where you have [0..1]*[0..∞] possible elements.

Comment: Honestly, Null Object Pattern sounds like a horrible idea. Imagine you have to create a speciall Null class for every node in the class hierarchy where a Null Object is required to be readily available! I'd say a better practice when null objects are expected is to check, for example, `if (c == null)`: if true, get out of code (_return false, throw exception, rollback, whatever_); otherwise (**standalone code, not an else block!**), continue execution.

Comment: @ADTC: I wouldn't advocate using the Null object pattern in *every* circumstance where null can arise.  There are *specific cases* where it is better (e.g. a "null" data sink implementation similar to /dev/null in UNIX).  Take a look in a Design Patterns book and you'll find plenty of examples.  In terms of avoiding an else block in favour of throwing an exception / returning from the method this is very much dependent on the context; Using an else block is often the correct choice and I'm not claiming in my answer that one should avoid using conditional logic!

Comment: That's what I keep telling my fellow developers! Returning null will always come back and kick your butt with cyclomatic complexity - always return a default value (like an empty list - easier to use for foreach/for loops and no conditional "check if null" code). I like your style @Adamski

Comment: I disagree. Sometimes no object is a perfectly fine response. What is the alternative? Throw an exception?  Some times no values is expected, so throwing exceptions in this case does not make sense.  Return a default value? Then you have to check if the default value is what you are expecting and handle that accordingly.  You are checking regardless.  Failure to check can always lead to unintended consequences, so that point is moot.

Answer (score 87):

Here's the reason.

In [Clean Code by Robert Martin](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132350882) he writes that returning null is bad design when you can instead return, say, empty array. Since expected result is an array, why not? It'll enable you to iterate over result without any extra conditions. If it's an integer, maybe 0 will suffice, if it's a hash, empty hash. etc.

The premise is to not force calling code to immediately handle issues. Calling code may not want to concern itself with them.  That's also why in many cases exceptions is better than nil.

Comment: This is the Null Object Pattern mentioned in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274792/is-returning-null-bad-design/1274822#1274822

Comment: The idea here is that on error, you return an empty/blank version of whatever object type you would return normally.  An empty array or string would work for those cases, for instance.  Returning "NULL" is appropriate when you would normally return a pointer (since NULL is essentially an empty pointer).  Returning NULL on error from a function that normally returns, say, a hash can be confusing.  Some languages handle this better than others but in general, consistency is the best practice.

Comment: You don't necessarily return on error, unless the error is somehow controlling the flow (which is not a good practice) or abstracted in API or interface. Errors are there to propagate to any level on which you decide to catch it, hence you don't have to deal with it in calling context. They are by default null-object-pattern-friendly.

Comment: Unfortunately, calling code doesn't always consider the case of an empty collection (much like it doesn't consider the null case). That may or may not be a problem.

Answer (score 40):

Good uses of returning null:

- If null is a valid *functional* result, for example: FindFirstObjectThatNeedsProcessing() can return null if not found and the caller should check accordingly.

Bad uses: Trying to replace or hide exceptional situations such as:

- catch(...) and return null
- API dependency initialization failed
- Out of disk space
- Invalid input parameters (programming error, inputs must be sanitized by the caller)
- etc

In those cases throwing an exception is more adequate since:

- A null return value provides no meaningful error info
- The immediate caller most likely cannot handle the error condition
- There is no guarantee that the caller is checking for null results

However, Exceptions should not be used to handle normal program operation conditions such as:

- Invalid username/password (or any user-provided inputs)
- Breaking loops or as non-local gotos

Comment: "Invalid username" seems like a good cause for an Exception, though.

Comment: Users entering invalid login/passwords should not be treated as an exceptional conditions, its part of normal program operation. However, the authentication system failing to respond (e.g. active directory) is an exceptional condition.

Comment: see:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/77127/when-to-throw-an-exception

Comment: I'd say it depends: `boolean login(String,String)` seems fine and so does `AuthenticationContext createAuthContext(String,String) throws AuthenticationException`

Comment: In your example, if there is no first object that needs processing, then there are two reasonable ways to handle that case.  The first is the Null Object pattern. Create a final subclass that represents a non-existent version of the class. It has reasonable defaults and throws exceptions when nonsense actions are requested. The other technique is Option.  This is what is available in Java8 and Scala.  Either of these show the developers intent.  null cannot show intent because it has too many possible meanings.  ** Showing Intent** is the most important aspect of code.

Comment: -Also, it should be noted that a function that checks for a valid username/password should also not return null.  Sounds like a boolean to me which can only be true or false. No need for Exceptions or nulls! 

-If you want to know why the username/password is invalid then consider wrapping the boolean in a ValidationResult Object.  In this case, the boolean result should never be null and the message should at least be defaulted to "unknow".  So any function in the future will have no problem handling this object. No need for Exceptions or nulls!

Comment: -.1 I think I agree with everything but the first statement "FindFirstObjectThatNeedsProcessing() can return null if not found and the caller should check accordingly." The function's name literally tells me it is going to return an Object and null is not an Object. If an Object is not found, then it seems like an exception can be thrown.

Answer (score 39):

Yes, returning NULL is a **terrible design**, in object-oriented world. In a nutshell, NULL usage leads to:

- ad-hoc error handling (instead of exceptions)
- ambiguous semantic
- slow instead of fast failing
- computer thinking instead of object thinking
- mutable and incomplete objects

Check this blog post for a detailed explanation: http://www.yegor256.com/2014/05/13/why-null-is-bad.html. More in my book [Elegant Objects](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1519166915), Section 4.1.

Comment: I agree strongly. I don't even like the null object pattern which appears to be a 'whitewash' delay tactic. Either your method is suppose to always succeed or it may not. If it should always succeed, then throw. If it may not succeed, then design the method so the consumer knows, e.g. `bool TryGetBlah(out blah)` or `FirstOrNull()` or `MatchOrFallback(T fallbackValue)`.

Comment: I too do not like return null. You are separating root cause from symptom, making debugging harder. Either throw an exception (fail fast), or call a checker method that returns a boolean first (e.g. `isEmpty()`) and only if it is true then call the method.  People argue against the 2nd one say it's poorer performance - but as Unix Philosophy says, "value human time over machine time" (i.e. trivially slower performance wastes less time than developers debugging code that is giving spurious errors).

Answer (score 21):

Who says this is bad design?

Checking for nulls is a common practice, even encouraged, otherwise you run the risk of NullReferenceExceptions everywhere. Its better to handle the error gracefully than throw exceptions when you don't need to.

Comment: +1. Code that throws exceptions for problems that can be mitigated on the spot makes me sad.

Comment: Yeah, imagine if every time you search on Google and got no results it threw an exception? Crazy! Lots of methods in the .NET framework can return null, so why shouldn't our own code do the same, when appropriate?

Comment: How sad do you get when coders forget to check for nulls and then get mysterious null pointer exceptions? Checked exceptions, where the compiler reminds the user they didn't deal with error conditions avoid taht class of coding errors.

Comment: @djna: I guess this is also sad but I've found that the same type of coders that "forget" to check for nulls are the ones who when dealing with checked exceptions frequently end up swallowing them.

Comment: It's easier to spot the presence of an empty catch block than the absence of a null-check.

Comment: @Tuzo, that's unfortunately true. But I agree with Preston that that we can spot these quite easily, and educate the offenders ;-)

Comment: What would be better is if there were non-nullable reference types in C#.  This is possible with Code Contracts in C# 4.0 but requires a little extra work (and patience waiting for .NET 4.0 to ship).

Comment: @Preston: I strongly disagree.  Absence of a null-check you'll spot immediately, when it crashes.  Swallowed exceptions can propogate mysterious and subtle errors for years...

Comment: I feel you've missed the point. Of course you need to check for nulls if they can be returned. The question is, if you are designing code, should you return null, which forces the user to check for nulls - which can be unnecessary given the alternatives. See the Null Object pattern, for example.

Comment: I cannot agree with the response. Error handling is usually a separate concern handled on the business logic level. Components used on lower level should avoid nulls completely, and if not possible: *fail fast*. Not failing fast will probably cause a more complicated, harder to track errors in the future. By handling nulls everywhere you basically grow technical debt around the source of the problem (the origin of null) instead of solving the origin. In my opinion we should "escape" from nullability as soon as possible (e.g. result from external lib) and then forget about it completely.

Comment: You don't need to check for NPE if there are no nulls

Answer (score 19):

Based on what you've said so far, I think there's not enough information.

Returning null from a CreateWidget()method seems bad.

Returning null from a FindFooInBar() method seems fine.

Comment: Similar to my convention: **Single item queries -** `Create...` returns a new instance, *or throws*; `Get...` returns an expected existing instance, *or throws*; `GetOrCreate...` returns an existing instance, or new instance if none exists, *or throws*; `Find...` returns an existing instance, if it exists, *or `null`*. **For collection queries -** `Get...` always returns a collection, which is empty if no matching items are found.

Comment: NULL's bad for reasons given in yegor256 & hakuinin's answer, returning a valid but empty object simplifies reasoning overal

Answer (score 16):

Its inventor [says](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Null-References-The-Billion-Dollar-Mistake-Tony-Hoare) it is a billion dollar mistake!

Answer (score 10):

It depends on the language you're using. If you're in a language like C# where the idiomatic way of indicating the lack of a value is to return null, then returning null is a good design if you don't have a value. Alternatively, in languages such as Haskell which idiomatically use the Maybe monad for this case, then returning null would be a bad design (if it were even possible).

Comment: +1 for mentioning maybe monad. I find the definition of `null` in languages such as C# and Java are often overloaded and given some meaning in the domain. If you look up the `null` keyword in the language specs, it simply means "an invalid pointer". That likely means nothing in any problem domain.

Comment: Problem is you don't know if it's a "missing value" `null` or "not initialized" `null`

Answer (score 6):

If you read all the answers it becomes clear the answer to this question depends on the kind of method.

Firstly, when something exceptional happens (IOproblem etc), logically exceptions are thrown. When exactly something is exceptional is probably something for a different topic..

Whenever a method is expected to possibly have no results there are two categories:

- If it is possible to return a *neutral value, do so*.
  Empty enumrables, strings etc are good examples
- If such a neutral value does not exist, *null should be returned*.
  As mentioned, the method is assumed to possibly have no result, so it is not exceptional, hence should not throw an exception. A neutral value is not possible (for example: 0 is not especially a neutral result, depending on the program)

Untill we have an official way to denote that a function can or cannot return null, I try to have a naming convention to denote so.
Just like you have the ***Try*Something()** convention for methods that are expected to fail, I often name my methods ***Safe*Something()** when the method returns a neutral result instead of null.

I'm not fully ok with the name yet, but couldn't come up with anything better. So I'm running with that for now.

Answer (score 6):

I have a convention in this area that served me well

For single item queries:

- `Create...` returns a new instance, *or throws*
- `Get...` returns an expected existing instance, *or throws*
- `GetOrCreate...` returns an existing instance, or new instance if none exists, *or throws*
- `Find...` returns an existing instance, if it exists, *or `null`*

For collection queries:

- `Get...` always returns a collection, which is empty if no matching[1] items are found

[1] given some criteria, explicit or implicit, given in the function name or as parameters.

Comment: Why GetOne and FindOne return different if not found?

Comment: I described the difference. I use `Get` when I *expect* it to be there, so that if it's not there, then it's an error and I throw - I never need to check the return value. I use `Find` if I really don't know if it's there or not - then I need to check the return value.

Answer (score 4):

It's not necessarily a bad design - as with so many design decisions, it depends.

If the result of the method is something that would not have a good result in normal use, returning null is fine:

```
object x = GetObjectFromCache();   // return null if it's not in the cache
```

If there really should always be a non-null result, then it might be better to throw an exception:

```
try {
   Controller c = GetController();    // the controller object is central to 
                                      //   the application. If we don't get one, 
                                      //   we're fubar

   // it's likely that it's OK to not have the try/catch since you won't 
   // be able to really handle the problem here
}
catch /* ... */ {
}
```

Comment: Though you can log a diagnostic error right there, then maybe rethrow the exception. Sometime First Failure Data Capture can be very helpful.

Comment: Or wrap the exception in a RuntimeException with diagnostic information in the message string.  Keep the information together.

Comment: Now (in 2018) I can no longer agree and in such cases we should favor returning `Optional<>`

Answer (score 4):

Exceptions are for *exception*al circumstances.

If your function is intended to find an attribute associated with a given object, and that object does has no such attribute, it may be appropriate to return null. If the object does not exist, throwing an exception may be more appropriate. If the function is meant to return a list of attributes, and there are none to return, returning an empty list makes sense - you're returning all zero attributes.

Comment: If you try to _use_ an attribute with no value, that merits an exception.  (I'm assuming your spec says the attribute is optional.)  Have a separate method to check whether its value has been set.

Answer (score 3):

It's fine to return null if doing so is meaningful in some way:

```
public String getEmployeeName(int id){ ..}
```

In a case like this it's meaningful to return null if the id doesn't correspond to an existing entity, as it allows you to distinguish the case where no match was found from a legitimate error.

People may think this is bad because it can be abused as a "special" return value that indicates an error condition, which is not so good, a bit like returning error codes from a function but confusing because the user has to check the return for null, instead of catching the appropriate exceptions, e.g.

```
public Integer getId(...){
   try{ ... ; return id; }
   catch(Exception e){ return null;}
}
```

Comment: Yup.  If you've got an error condition, throw an exception.

Comment: This is one case where an exception would be warranted. If you're requesting the name of an employee that doesn't exist, something is obviously going wrong.

Comment: I think that's a bit literal, Thorarin-you can quibble with my example, certainly, but I'm sure you can imagine some instance of a function that returns a matching value, or null if there's no match. How about getting a value from a key in a hashtable? (should've thought of that example in the first place).

Comment: A hash table returning null for a key that doesn't exist is bad. Doing so automatically means that you can't store null as a value without inconsistent code.

Answer (score 2):

For certain scenarios, you want to notice a failure as soon as it happens.

Checking against NULL and not asserting (for programmer errors) or throwing (for user or caller errors) in the failure case can mean that later crashes are harder to track down, because the original odd case wasn't found.

Moreover, ignoring errors can lead to security exploits.  Perhaps the null-ness came from the fact that a buffer was overwritten or the like.  Now, you are *not* crashing, which means the exploiter has a chance to execute in your code.

Answer (score 2):

What alternatives do you see to returning null?

I see two cases:

- findAnItem( id ).  What should this do if the item is not found

In this case we could: Return Null or throw a (checked) exception (or maybe create an item and return it)

- listItemsMatching (criteria) what should this return if nothing is found?

In this case we could return Null, return an empty list or throw an Exception.

I believe that return null may be less good than the alternatives becasue it requires the client to remember to check for null, programmers forget and code

```
x = find();
x.getField();  // bang null pointer exception
```

In Java, throwing a checked exception, RecordNotFoundException, allows the compiler to remind the client to deal with case.

I find that searches returning empty lists can  be quite convenient - just populate the display with all the contents of the list, oh it's empty, the code "just works".

Comment: Throwing exceptions to indicate a condition which is expected to possibly happen during the normal flow of the program leads to really ugly code, of the sort try { x = find() } catch (RecordNotFound e) { // do stuff }.

Comment: Returning empty lists is a good solution but only when the method is in a context that can return lists. For "findById" situations, you need to return null. I don't like RecordNotFound exceptions.

Comment: So that's the crux of our differentce in opinion. To my eyes there's not much difference in beauty between x = find(); if ( x = null ) { work } else { do stuff } and try catch. And, if necessary I'm prepared to sacrifice beauty for code correctness. Too often in my life I encounter code where return values have not been checked.

Answer (score 2):

Make them call another method after the fact to figure out if the previous call was null. ;-) Hey, it was [good enough for JDBC](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#wasNull())

Answer (score 1):

Well, it sure depends of the purpose of the method ... Sometimes, a better choice would be to throw an exception. It all depends from case to case.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, returning NULL is the right thing to do, but specifically when you're dealing with sequences of different sorts (arrays, lists, strings, what-have-you) it is probably better to return a zero-length sequence, as it leads to shorter and hopefully more understandable code, while not taking much more writing on API implementer's part.

Answer (score 1):

The base idea behind this thread is to program defensively. That is, code against the unexpected.
There is an array of different replies:

**Adamski** suggests looking at Null Object Pattern, with that reply being up voted for that suggestion.

**Michael Valenty** also suggests a naming convention to tell the developer what may be expected.
**ZeroConcept** suggests a proper use of Exception, if that is the reason for the NULL.
And others.

If we make the "rule" that we always want to do defensive programming then we can see that these suggestions are valid.

But we have 2 development scenarios.

Classes "authored" by a developer: The Author

Classes "consumed" by another(maybe) developer: the Developer

Regardless of whether a class returns NULL for methods with a return value or not,
the Developer will need to test if the object is valid.

If the developer cannot do this, then that Class/method is not deterministic.
That is, if the "method call" to get the object does not do what it "advertises" (eg getEmployee) it has broken the contract.

As an author of a class, I always want to be as kind and defensive ( and deterministic) when creating a method.

So given that either NULL or the NULL OBJECT (eg if(employee as NullEmployee.ISVALID)) needs to be checked 
and that may need to happen with a collection of Employees, then the null object approach is the better approach.

But I also like **Michael Valenty's** suggestion of naming the method that MUST return null eg getEmployeeOrNull.

An Author who throws an exception is removing the choice for the developer to test the object's validity, 
which is very bad on a collection of objects, and forces the developer into exception handling 
 when branching their consuming code.

As a developer consuming the class, I hope the author gives me the ability to avoid or program for the null situation
 that their class/methods may be faced with.

So as a developer I would program defensively against NULL from a method.
If the author has given me a contract that always returns a object (NULL OBJECT always does) 
and that object has a method/property by which to test the validity of the object,
then I would use that method/property to continue using the object, else the object is not valid 
and I cannot use it.

Bottom line is that the Author of the Class/Methods must provide mechanisms 
that a Developer can use in their defensive programming. That is, a clearer intention of the method.

The Developer should always use defensive programming to test the validity of the objects returned 
from another class/method.

regards

GregJF

Answer (score 0):

Other options to this, are:
returning some value that indicates success or not (or type of an error), but if you just need boolean value that will indicate success / fail, returning null for failure, and an object for success wouldn't be less correct, then returning true/false and getting the object through parameter.
Other approach would to to use exception to indicates failures, but here - there are actually many more voices, that say this is a BAD practice (as using exceptions may be convenient but has many disadvantages).
So I personally don't see anything bad in returning null as indication that something went wrong, and checking it later (to actually know if you have succeeded or not). Also, blindly thinking that your method will not return NULL, and then base your code on it, may lead to other, sometimes hard to find, errors (although in most cases it will just crash your system :), as you will reference to 0x00000000 sooner or later).

Answer (score 0):

> Unintended null functions can arise during the development of a complex programs, and like dead code, such occurrences indicate serious flaws in program structures.
>
> A null function or method is often used as the default behavior of a revectorable function or overrideable method in an object framework.

[Null_function @wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_function)

Answer (score 0):

If the code is something like:

```
command = get_something_to_do()

if command:  # if not Null
    command.execute()
```

If you have a dummy object whose execute() method does nothing, and you return that instead of Null in the appropriate cases, you don't have to check for the Null case and can instead just do:

```
get_something_to_do().execute()
```

So, here the issue is not between checking for NULL vs. an exception, but is instead between the caller having to handle special non-cases differently (in whatever way) or not.

Answer (score 0):

For my use case I needed to return a Map from method and then looking for a specific key. But if I return an empty Map, then it will lead to NullPointerException and then it wont be much different returning null instead of an empty Map.
 But from Java8 onward we could use [Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html). The above is the very reason Optional concept was introduced.

Answer (score -2):

G'day,

Returning NULL when you are unable to create a new object is standard practise for many APIs.

Why the hell it's bad design I have no idea.

**Edit:** This is true of languages where you don't have exceptions such as C where it has been the convention for many years.

HTH

'Avahappy,

Comment: If you are unable to create an object, you should really throw an Exception. If you are unable to find an object that matches some query, then returning null is the way to go.

Comment: @Thilo, show me how to do that in C and I'll be most interested.

Comment: @RobWells C is not an object-oriented language, but this question is tagged as "oop"

Comment: @yegor256 You are right. And I missed the original OOP tag. But, as BS said a class in C++ is just a struct with some additional member functions added and some fancy memory management happening internally. But if an API is suuposed to return a struct, then returning NUL when you can't create the struct is often the convention.