# return nothing , using array == null or array.length == 0?

Tags: java, null, empty-list

Supposing I have a function with following signature:

```
Foo[] getSomeFoos() 
{
      //return null         --- option A 
      or 
      //return new Foo[0];  --- option B
}
```

What is the recommended practice to return the value indicating there is no elements returned? Any pros or cons for each option?

Comment: See [
Is returning null bad design?
](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274792/is-returning-null-bad-design)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If your method `GetSomeFoos()` actually 'found' 0 elements, then it should return `new Foo[0]`.

If there was some sort of error, you should throw an `Exception`.

The reason is because users shouldn't have to look for nulls:

```
for (Foo f: GetSomeFoos()) {
    // do stuff
}
```

In the above case, if `GetSomeFoos` returned `null`, a user will have to deal with an `NullPointerException`.  But, if you return an empty array, the code will never enter the loop, and the user will not have to deal with an exception.

Comment: return null might be reasonable. I would use it to mean there are no kind Foo that could possibly be returned. In all other cases, returning empty array is most sensible.

Comment: @Joshua, I suppose I could think of a reason why I could return null.  But usually I would return am empty list/array.

Comment: Whether to return null or empty object entirely depends on the method usage. If this method is called by a client and exposed as an API then throwing exception is better , but if it is used within ur package and never used by client then returning null is ok.

Answer (score 0):

Whether to return null or empty object entirely depends on the method usage. If this method is called by a client and exposed as an API then throwing exception is better , but if it is used within ur package and never used by client  then returning null is ok.

Answer (score 0):

Returning null is more efficient, since you avoid the overhead of creating a new array or collection object. It's true that you then have to add a null check at the point where you use the function's output, but the overhead for that (in Java and almost all languages) is negligible. I also think that checking for null is a good habit to get into, especially when dealing with third-party libraries.

The downside is that you make the code more verbose.

If you do return an empty array, you can mitigate the performance hit by re-using the same object. Create an immutable constant, and return that:

```
private static final String[] EMPTY = {};
```

Or:

```
private static final List<String> EMPTY = 
    Collections.unmodifiableList(new ArrayList<String>());
```

Comment: You are arguing the performance gain between: `return null` and `return new Object[0]`?  I can't believe that allocating 0 space takes much longer than not allocating any space.  (Wait, is there a difference?)

Comment: Premature optimization is the root of all evil.  Don't return null, certainly not for this reason.

Comment: There's a big difference. A Java array is an object - it's not like C, where an array is just a pointer to an allocated block on the heap. You need to allocate space for the array object, and initialize it, even if it has zero elements.

Comment: With escape analysis, a fixed-size array could be stack allocated which is more or less a no-op. If you expect the reference to escape a lot (and you can prove the allocations to be a problem), you can store a zero-element array in a static final field and return the same object every time you find zero hits.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer **zero-size array**.

It's safer(avoid NPE) and easier(no need null check).

Answer (score 0):

From [Effective Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321356683) (2nd ed) - item 43: return empty arrays or collections, not nulls

*In summary, there is no reason ever to return null from an array- or collection-valued method instead of returning an empty array or collection*