# java: Trying to return a string value from an array of strings via a method

Tags: java, arrays, string

```
public String GetValue(String key) {
    for (int i = 1; i<=length; i++) {
        if (key.equals(keyArr[i])) {
            return valueArr[i];
        }
    }
}
public String GetKey(String value) {
    String key;
    for (int i = 1; i<=length; i++) {
        if (value.equals(valueArr[i])) {
            key = keyArr[i];
            return key;
        }
    }
}
```

I get an error "this method must return a result of type string". But the two arrays valueArr and keyArr are both String type arrays. I know that the value of keyArr[i] and valueArr[i] are strings because if I change the return type of the method to something else it says that it expected something else and got a string.

Comment: Does this even compile? It should be complaining about a missing return statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because it does not always return a String. E.g. if the key is not found, `if (key.equals(keyArr[i])) {` will never be true and hence, `return valueArr[i];` will never get executed.

To fix this, you need to do the following:

- Add `return` statement after `for loop`, to return *something* if no match is found, e.g.:

  ```
  public String GetValue(String key) {
      for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
          if (key.equals(keyArr[i])) {
              return valueArr[i];
          }
      }
      return null;
  }
  ```
- Handle the `return type` in the calling method (i.e. add a null check or perform an appropriate action if no match found).

Comment: you can't start indexing from `1` to `<=length`

Comment: @Mohsen_Fatemi corrected, thanks for pointing it out. I actually used the example from question only.

Comment: i don't know how does it work without `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException` for @Johndoe ? :))

Comment: @DarshanMehta yw ;)

Comment: i meant for that to be a zero,  i<=length-1 would work as well thanks

Comment: @Johndoe even with this condition , when you start from `1` you are missing the first element

Answer (score 1):

The issue less with the "of type String" and more with the "must." What happens, for example, if you pass in a string that doesn't appear in the array? In that case, your function never actually returns anything.

If you're guaranteed that the key will always exist, consider putting a line at the end like

```
throw new RuntimeException("Key not found?");
```

so that the function doesn't just drop off the end. Alternatively, try adding a line like

```
return null;
```

so that you explicitly return something in that case.

Comment: `return null` may not be [the best option](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1274865/4280359). Why not something like `-1`? It is already used in some methods like `binarySearch` on an array.

Comment: Why not return -1? Because return type is `String`. Apart from that, @templatetypedef also offered a different, perhaps preferable solution using an Exception.

Comment: Exception is better here... But returning `null` can become really problematic.

Comment: @GrzegorzGórkiewicz I agree that `null` might not be the best return value here. That was mostly showing off another way to get the error to stop, which was by always returning a value.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is when you Write the type `String` you must `return` a `String` value in your method. so for Example `GetValue` Could be like this :

```
public String GetValue(String key) {
    for (int i = 0; i<keyArr.length; i++) {
        if (key.equals(keyArr[i])) {
            return valueArr[i];
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

pay attention to indexes , it **must** start from `0` to `length -1` in arrays

and your second method :

```
public String GetKey(String value) {
    String key = "";
    for (int i = 0; i<value.length; i++) {
        if (value.equals(valueArr[i])) {
            key = keyArr[i];
            return key;
        }
    }
    return key ;
}
```