# code coverage don't recognize my spied function

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, istanbul

I have this function on my service.

```
  addTeamMember(data): Observable<any> {
   if (data && typeof data === 'object') {
    return this.http.post<any>(`${this.baseUrl}/members`, 
     JSON.stringify(data), { headers: this.headers });
   } else {
    return null;
   }
```

}

and i test this with:

```
it('should be create a new member', () => {
const data = {
  name: 'Rodolfo Lenin',
  lastName: 'xxxx xxxx',
  rol: 'Front-End',
  gender: 'male'
};
spy = spyOn(teamService, 'addTeamMember');
spy.and.callThrough();
spy.and.callFake(function() {});
spy.and.returnValue(data);
response = teamService.addTeamMember(of(data));
console.log(response, data, 'werr');
// expect(teamService.addTeamMember).toHaveBeenCalled();
expect(data).toEqual(jasmine.any(Object));
expect(response).toEqual(data); });
```

i dont know why test coverage don't recognize this call
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iiTgO.png)

Comment: Side note: You should not be writing run time checks for something  to be of type object. Instead, you should type your parameter and let the compiler check it for you

Answer (score 0):

You are stubbing out your `teamMember.addTeamMember` that's why  it's never being called. You can verify that with `console.log` statements (or just trust your code coverage tool ;)

You should stub out `http.post` so that your `addTeamMember` is actually being tested.

Having said that, your test doesn't make sense:

- You are passing an observable to your function when it expects an object
- You are faking your method to return an object instead of an observable

Possible solution

```
 it('creates a new member', () => {

    const data = {
      name: 'Rodolfo Lenin',
      lastName: 'xxxx xxxx',
      rol: 'Front-End',
      gender: 'male'
    };

    spyOn(httpService, 'post').and.returnValue(of(data));

    teamService.addTeamMember(data).subscribe((responseData) => {
        expect(responseData).toEqual(data);
    });
 });
```

Note that you should write another test for the case where your service returns null. However, returning null because invalid parameters were passed in is generally considered an anti-pattern. See [Is returning null bad design?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274792/is-returning-null-bad-design)

Also, there's a different approach suggested by Angular https://angular.io/guide/http#testing-http-requests

And here's a fun conversation about checking parameters https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20091210-00/?p=15713

Comment: thank for you answer, i fix the two problems that you list, but still understanding what i need to do, to fix the coverage problem.

Comment: Instead of calling `spy.and.callFake(function() {});` (and all the other functions that spy on your own service). You should be calling `spyOn(httpService, 'post');` That way, your function is called, but Angular's HTTP service is faked

Comment: i change that to only     `spy = spyOn(teamService, 'addTeamMember');
    spy.and.returnValue(of(data));`, and coverage still not working.