# Other ways to check for not null in Java

Tags: java

I have a lot of this kind of code in my project:

```
if (entityRepository.saveEntity(new RemoteEntityBuilder()
   .appId(appId)
   .nameSpace(nameSpace)
   .entityType(entityType)
   .entityId(entityId)
   .blobs(Lists.list(new RemoteBlobBuilder()
      .blobName(blobName)
      .blobStream(new SimpleRemoteInputStream(inputStream))
      .build()))
   .build()) != null) {  
   // Meaning entity was saved
} else {
   // Meaning entity was not saved
}
```

The `saveEntity` method returns either NULL (if operation failed) or the object/entity that was saved if the operation was successful. My question is, is there a better way to represent this code with the use of `!= null` for instance:

```
if(entityRepository.saveEntity(...)) {
}
```

Or something else.

UPDATE:

The `saveEntity` method is this

```
  @Override public RemoteEntity saveEntity(RemoteEntity entity)
      throws NotBoundException, RemoteException {
    RemoteEntities remoteEntities = saveEntities(new RemoteEntity[] {entity});
    return remoteEntities != null ? remoteEntities.entities().stream().findFirst().get() : null;
  }
```

Here's how it looks now thanks to YCF_L:

```
  entityRepository.saveEntity(new RemoteEntityBuilder()
                .appId(appId)
                .nameSpace(nameSpace)
                .entityType(entityType)
                .entityId(entityId)
                .blobs(Lists.list(new RemoteBlobBuilder()
                    .blobName(blobName)
                    .blobStream(new SimpleRemoteInputStream(inputStream))
                    .build()))
                .build()).ifPresentOrElse(remoteEntity -> {
              pubSubService.updated(remoteEntity.appId(), remoteEntity.nameSpace(),
                  remoteEntity.entityType(), remoteEntity.entityId());
              setStatus(Status.SUCCESS_CREATED);
            }, () -> {
              setStatus(Status.CLIENT_ERROR_BAD_REQUEST);
            });
```

Here's how the code looks in the IDE (looks pretty clean to me):

[image]

Comment: What did you mean by *is there a better way to represent this code with the use of != null for instance:* ?

Comment: I mean I can build a new method like `saveEntityBoolean` that wraps this but that's a bit an overkill and API looks terrible. Something like, `if(saved) { // do stuff }`

Comment: using exceptions properly might be an approach.. and you avoid the usage of null.. this method "saveEntities" probably should throw some exception if it not succeeds saving the entity

Comment: also I prefer to avoid returning null on methods, basically to make the client code cleaner, check this interesting post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274792/is-returning-null-bad-design

Comment: @quarks I think it is ugly the way you are building your object, I would create a separate variable, this can make your code more clear and clean

Comment: @YCF_L does it look like RxJava mess?

Comment: @quarks I don't get you, but what I mean is to create `RemoteEntity entity = new RemoteEntityBuilder()
                .appId(appId)
                .nameSpace(nameSpace)
                .entityType(entityType)
                .entityId(entityId)
                .blobs(Lists.list(new RemoteBlobBuilder()
                    .blobName(blobName)
                    .blobStream(new SimpleRemoteInputStream(inputStream))
                    .build()))
                .build()` and then `entityRepository.saveEntity(entity)` this can be more clear

Comment: @YCF_L I updated the question with the actual code in the IDE, do you think the code is not clean?

Comment: No, no, I mean, just to use something like this https://ideone.com/Y4eVlg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use `Optional` in your case :

```
public Optional<RemoteEntity> saveEntity(RemoteEntity entity) throws NotBoundException, RemoteException {
    RemoteEntities remoteEntities = saveEntities(new RemoteEntity[]{entity});
    return remoteEntities.entities().stream()
            .findFirst();
}
```

and then :

```
if(entityRepository.saveEntity(...).isPresent()) {
   ...       
}
```

In fact you have many choices with `Optional`, you can use `ifPresent` also :

```
entityRepository.saveEntity(...)
    .ifPresent(r -> ..)
```

Or throw an exception:

```
entityRepository.saveEntity(...)
    .orElseThrow(() -> ..)
```

Comment: Yeah, this actually makes sense

Comment: `stream().findFirst()` actually returns an Optional. You don't need `.orElse(Optional.empty())`

Answer (score 1):

What is "better" may be a matter of opinion.

Given your example, the way to achieve that would be to create another method that calls `saveEntity()` and returns `true` or `false`.  (I do wonder why `saveEntity()` doesn't throw an exception if its operations fails -- that would be more normal in my experience.)

If you simply don't like that the comparison is hard to spot, you might reverse the order:

```
if (null != entityRepository.saveEntity(...))
```

I would probably move the call outside of the if entirely, as I find side effects in conditionals potentially confusing.

```
RemoteEntity myEntity = entityRepository.saveEntity(...)
if (myEntity != null) ...
```